# Require pointer or vector argument

Tags: c++, templates, instantiation

I am defining a function to write 2d ,1d array, or vector of "points" into a file using template. When compliling, there goes an error saying "error C2109: subscript requires array or pointer type" indicating that the variable "input" should be array or pointer type. But I just want to instantiate the function like the follwoing

```
writers<Array_2d, 3, 4>(my2darray,1);
```

or

```
writers<std::vector<double>, 10, 1>(myvector,1);
```

The Array_2d is a self defined class, since I already defined  Array_2d that allow [][] operator and it should not bother to tell it is a pointer or array whatever. How can I fix the problem since I want to instantiate the function by a class that have well defined [][] operator;

```
template <class item, int DIM1, int DIM2>
void writers(const item & input, int flag=1)
{
    using namespace std;
    ofstream fout;
    if (flag == 0)
    {
        fout.open(filename, std::ios_base::app);
    }
    else
    {
        fout.open(filename);
    }

    fout.setf(std::ios_base::floatfield, std::ios_base::fixed);
    fout.precision(8);
    for (int i = 0; i <DIM1; i++)
    {
        if (DIM2 > 1)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < DIM2; j++)
            {
                fout.width(17);
                fout << input[i][j];
            }
            fout << "\n";
        }
        else
        {
            fout.width(17);
            fout << input[i];
        }
        fout << endl;
    }
    fout.close();
}
```

Comment: *Specialization?* Or just plain overloading (instead of templates for the argument)?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude can you give a hint? I want the code be short and concise

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In C++17, with `if constexpr`, you might do something similar to:

```
template <typename Container>
void writers(const Container& input, ofstream& fout)
{
    if constexpr (std::is_same<double, typename Container::value_type>::value) {
        // 1D
        fout.setf(std::ios_base::floatfield, std::ios_base::fixed);
        fout.precision(8);
        for (auto& d : input) {
            fout.width(17);
            fout << d;
        }
        fout << endl;
    } else {
        // 2D (or 3D, ...)
        for (const auto& inner : input) {
            writers(inner, fout);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I have just tried your answer, it works Thanks your help!. @jarod42

Comment: Better than just "thanks" comment, you can accept/upvote answer.

Comment: Thanks for your kind remind, the answer is know accepted @jarod42